# Use arrow keys c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm new to c++ and I'm not sure how WM_KEYDOWN works. I want to have a case for each arrow key (UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT)

Thanks

Comment: You should Google your questions before asking them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the [WM_KEYDOWN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28VS.85%29.aspx), the wParam of the [message loop](http://winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html) contains the virtual code key - therefore, you can use the following:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    switch (wParam) {
        case VK_UP:
            // up was pressed
        break;

        case VK_DOWN:
            // down was pressed
        break;

        // etc.
    }
break;
```

The whole reference on virtual key codes [can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx).